# Gradle Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I got this error while executing a Gradle Project in Java using JavaFX.
My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-youtube', version: 'v3-rev222-1.25.0'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.graphics' ]
    version = "11.0.2"
}

mainClassName = "Younify_Gradle.Main"
```

Any ideas or is anything in my build.gradle wrong?

Comment: Try again bumping the JavaFX plugin version to 0.0.8?

Comment: still the same error

Comment: How do you run it? With `./gradlew run` or from your IDE? Try the former from a terminal

Comment: @JoséPereda I have a similar problem, but ./gradlew run works for me. Do you happen to know what I need to change in order to start it succesfully in IntelliJ ?